# The value for property 'buildConfigFields' cannot be changed any further

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've just updated in Android Studio the Gradle version from **7.2** to **7.4.2** and as soon as it tries to build the project it fails with an exception:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The value for property 'buildConfigFields' cannot be changed any further.
```

Rolling back to 7.2 fixes the issues.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same problem and I couldn't find the solution. Thanks!
Here is the updated installation instructions:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/secrets-gradle-plugin


(BTW, if you post your solution I'll upvote it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## SOLVED

I was using a deprecated gradle plugin.

**Deprecated:** `com.google.secrets_gradle_plugin`

**New:** `com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin`

Comment: I looked through the logs and found nothing, how did you realized t was a deprecated plugin???

Comment: @MikoChu I created an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/233479466) on Issue Tracker.

Answer (score 3):

**Here is the most recent solution update.**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/secrets-gradle-plugin

Comment: Thank you for anwser. It is recommended to include code snippet as possible since outside link maybe changed or removed.

Comment: Better go here directly ... the google docs send you here anyway for the newest update -> https://github.com/google/secrets-gradle-plugin